# Chrome CSS issue with input "No file chosen" title is not inheriting padding?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am trying to add a few CSS attributes to an input field, using Chrome - everything seems to work except for the fact that the "No file chosen" text does not seem to inherit the padding value. If I remove all CSS the "no file chosen" remains directly in line with regards to the button, but  after adding CSS it causes it to appear higher as if this text is not inheriting the padding value?

Here is the complete CSS that causes this issue:

```
.inputtest{
    line-height:1.5em;
    border:5px solid #3a3a3a;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:20px;
    width:71%;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;    
}​
```

Please see: http://jsfiddle.net/A6LuR/3/

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It looks like a bug to me. Works correctly in IE8+9 and renders a very different control in FF.

Comment: It is better to use this trick for the `input type=file`. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html

Comment: Thanks Praveen, but all I want is for the "No file chosen" text to render directly in line with the input in Chrome. I'll bookmark this though for next time.

Comment: I filed a ticket on Chromium: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=164255

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Css problem is `padding` property.

this code give you similar design

CSS:

```
.inputtestHolder{
    border:5px solid #3a3a3a;
    padding:10px;
    margin-left:20px;
    width:71%;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="inputtestHolder">
<input type="file">
</div>
```

I hope that helped

​